# What is the signature value output by ZCertificate/ZCrypto encoded?

Tags: go

The signature value output by ZCertificate/ZCrypto is different from that output by OpenSSL. For example, OpenSSL outputs `ba:de:13:f9:3f:af:4b:c2:01:48:2e:33:9c:23:15:93:a1:d4:21:d8:f4:14:c0:5f:0e:53:38:f2:16:96:a8:9c:b6:ae:69:af:1c:94:27:ea:e3:71:63:03:7f:38:53:de:28:e4:ef:ab:04:dd:eb:39:2e:9f:59:1a:12:0f:f8:61:09:78:16:95:44:7f:3a:05:81:01:7a:ca:d2:38:69:5e:41:e8:aa:7d:ea:01:ba:d2:0e:d7:49:bd:8e:8e:35:d9:77:3a:3b:0b:89:97:03:b8:3c:c9:70:43:99:f9:c9:8f:95:2c:e6:2d:1a:60:9e:c6:b1:b4:d7:cf:07:78:35:ec`, but ZCertificate outputs `nkarw83ve0xgkiaut9h4zicr+tiw5zkna4aph3ggml4/cl5c4f3wjb2r1fc4mlpelcjaplknuvf3qqbof+ydz1sidigzcf8masymklb17foszi2ppxmwritis/dja3nm7pwnoggq1ss6dw80dsvbnp3t7mfgnnpjetmgckwd/pe=`. The output by ZCertificate looks like base64-encode. However, I tried but fail to match it with the output by OpenSSL. I read the source code of ZCertificate (https://github.com/zmap/zcertificate/tree/master/cmd/zcertificate). Line 68  of main.go shows that `parsed , err := x509.ParseCertificate(raw)` in the func `processCertificate`. That is, ZCertificate invokes the x509 of ZCrypto (https://github.com/zmap/zcrypto/tree/master/x509). Line 1614 of x509.go shows `out.Signature = in.SignatureValue.RightAlign()`. I am not familiar with Golang. I wonder how the signature value is encoded in ZCrypto. Do any Golang programmers or related experts know the answer? Could you tell me it? Thanks!

I tried to encode `ba:de:13:f9:3f:af:4b:c2:01:48:2e:33:9c:23:15:93:a1:d4:21:d8:f4:14:c0:5f:0e:53:38:f2:16:96:a8:9c:b6:ae:69:af:1c:94:27:ea:e3:71:63:03:7f:38:53:de:28:e4:ef:ab:04:dd:eb:39:2e:9f:59:1a:12:0f:f8:61:09:78:16:95:44:7f:3a:05:81:01:7a:ca:d2:38:69:5e:41:e8:aa:7d:ea:01:ba:d2:0e:d7:49:bd:8e:8e:35:d9:77:3a:3b:0b:89:97:03:b8:3c:c9:70:43:99:f9:c9:8f:95:2c:e6:2d:1a:60:9e:c6:b1:b4:d7:cf:07:78:35:ec` with/without colon into base64. But the result does not match `nkarw83ve0xgkiaut9h4zicr+tiw5zkna4aph3ggml4/cl5c4f3wjb2r1fc4mlpelcjaplknuvf3qqbof+ydz1sidigzcf8masymklb17foszi2ppxmwritis/dja3nm7pwnoggq1ss6dw80dsvbnp3t7mfgnnpjetmgckwd/pe=`. I expect to get the way to get `nkarw83ve0xgkiaut9h4zicr+tiw5zkna4aph3ggml4/cl5c4f3wjb2r1fc4mlpelcjaplknuvf3qqbof+ydz1sidigzcf8masymklb17foszi2ppxmwritis/dja3nm7pwnoggq1ss6dw80dsvbnp3t7mfgnnpjetmgckwd/pe=` from `ba:de:13:f9:3f:af:4b:c2:01:48:2e:33:9c:23:15:93:a1:d4:21:d8:f4:14:c0:5f:0e:53:38:f2:16:96:a8:9c:b6:ae:69:af:1c:94:27:ea:e3:71:63:03:7f:38:53:de:28:e4:ef:ab:04:dd:eb:39:2e:9f:59:1a:12:0f:f8:61:09:78:16:95:44:7f:3a:05:81:01:7a:ca:d2:38:69:5e:41:e8:aa:7d:ea:01:ba:d2:0e:d7:49:bd:8e:8e:35:d9:77:3a:3b:0b:89:97:03:b8:3c:c9:70:43:99:f9:c9:8f:95:2c:e6:2d:1a:60:9e:c6:b1:b4:d7:cf:07:78:35:ec`.

Comment: The `xx:yy…` is a so-called [hex-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) with the encodings of individual octets (bytes) separated from each other with `:`. The latter `nkarw83v…` is [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). They both (supposedly) encode the same data (a sequence of bytes).

Comment: Hex-encoding can be dealt with in Go using [`encoding/hex`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex).

Comment: @kostix How to verify the two encoded results are identical in essence? That is, how to convert one to the other (using Python)? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is "signature value"? I mean, what particular operation do you perform which produces that base64-encoded blob? Is it signing a message with a (private key/part of) X.509 certificate?

Comment: Also: why do you need to «…verify the two encoded results are identical in essence»? I mean, the only use of a message signature is verifying that it's created by the owner of a particular certificate (that is, the owner proves possessing its private part and their identity at the same time); the bit-exactness between two representations of a particular signature need not necessarily be the same if these signatures are represented in different containers/formats. Actually only the actual signature "blobs" need be exact. And still, what comparing two signatures will give to you?

Comment: @kostix Answer to the first question: The base64-encoded and hex-encoded signature values were output by OpenSSL and ZCertificate, respectively. They came from one certificate signed with a private key.  Answer to the second question: I want to make it clear that OpenSSL and ZCertificate output the same signature value for one certificate, regardless of the encoding ways.

Comment: «The base64-encoded and hex-encoded signature values were output by OpenSSL and ZCertificate», sorry, that's not an answer: `openssl` provides several dozens of subcommands, and most of them have multiple modes of operation each. Not all of these commands work on X.509 certificates, but still. So, let me repeat: Is it signing a message with a (private key/part of) X.509 certificate? The README.md for "ZCertificate" states «ZCertificate parses X.509 certificates and runs ZLint.», so I'm now completely lost, TBH.

Comment: @kostix Tha signature value is a part of an X.509 certificate and it signed the tbsCertificate. ZCertificate invokes ZLint to append the lint results as the third part of ZCertificate's output. The signature value here is contained in the second part of ZCertificate's output, which is process by x509.go of ZCrypto.